# PHP $GLOBALS as array issue

Tags: php, arrays, global

I am trying to store an array in $GLOBALS and using the following code:

```
$GLOBALS['cols'] = array();
```

But it seems to be printing the word 'Array' to the actual page where this is being called.

Any ideas as to why it's doing this or how I can get around it.

Comment: If you try echoing an Array, then it will literally echo the word 'Array'.... you have to echo the individual values in that array (`foreach $_GLOBALS['cols'] as $value { echo $value; }`).... so show the code that you're using  to display this

Comment: `$GLOBALS['cols'] = array();` Are you using the $ sign?

Comment: Yeh I understand that but it's the line of code above that seems to be echoing that word, even though it clearly isn't supposed to. It should just init the array but is echoing it too...

Comment: can you do a `print_r($GLOBALS)` and show us the response?

Comment: An assignment doesn't print anything. The `Array` output is coming from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Found the issue, there was another variable named $cols that was being echoed so it was echoing 'Array'. Changed $GLOBALS['cols'] to $GLOBALS['columns'] and it's been removed. Thank you for the replies

Answer (score 0):

There was another variable named $cols that was being echoed so it was echoing 'Array'. Changed $GLOBALS['cols'] to $GLOBALS['columns'] and it's been removed. Thank you for the replies